# How to correctly interpret gnuplot documentation? (4#4, 5#5, 6#6, etc.)

Tags: gnuplot, hashtag

The title of this question may sound a bit crazy, but: How do I correctly read and interpret gnuplot documentations [like the one for border](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node162.html) or [the one for xtics](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node295.html)?

---

For example, in the first link it says

> In detail, **5#5integer6#6** should be the sum of the appropriate entries from the following table:

In the second one it says

> **rotate by 5#5ang6#6** asks for rotation by 5#5ang6#6 degrees, supported by some terminal types.

---

Can someone explain to me how to interpret `5#5` or `6#6` correctly? Is the documentation just broken and `5#5` means `<`, while `6#6` means `>`? This would not make sense to me, because in the documentation for xtics it also says `{axis 4#4 border}`, so it must have something to do with the number, yet I am too blind to see it.

---

Additional: This is not critical, I can figure out the usage from the "Syntax" given (e.g. I currently use `set xtics rotate by 45 right` in my plot), yet I just would like no know what I'm missing here.

Comment: Please do not use that ancient documentation, but rather an up-to-date pdf or at least http://www.gnuplotting.org/manpage-gnuplot-4-6/, especially because what you describe is just a matter of wrong formatting of that html-documentation. See http://www.gnuplotting.org/manpage-gnuplot-4-6/#Q1-1-394

Comment: @Christoph: Thanks for the link, I will try to use this from now on. I have to admit that most of the time I had a question regarding gnuplot I just opened up google, where then most of the time that ancient documentation shows up on the first page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, those are not supposed to be there.  That is likely because of some internal code in the documentation source that got carried over to the html output.  Drop the 5#5, 6#6, and so on and it will read correctly.  For example, the first one should read

> In detail, **integer** should be the sum of the appropriate entries from the following table.

and the second one should read

> **rotate by ang** asks for rotation by **ang** degrees, supported by some terminal types.

You can also get documentation from gnuplot itself with the help command.  For example, to look up the border topic, use `help border` or `?border`.

Comment: Thanks, I nearly thought that I'm crazy because I could not figure out what they mean. Now I have the confirmation that I'm not (at least not due to this :D). Thanks for the advice with `help` and `?`.